# Load Error : no such file to load -- watir/testcase after upgrading to watir 4.0.2

Tags: ruby, watir

I just upgraded to `watir 4.0.2` from `watir 2.0.4` and i am getting the below error,

```
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `gem_original
_require': no such file to load -- watir/testcase (LoadError)
```

I searched about the error and was not able to find a solution to it.

**Gem List**

```
abstract (1.0.0)                    
actionmailer (3.2.8, 3.0.0)                 
actionpack (3.2.8, 3.0.0)                   
activemodel (3.2.8, 3.0.0)                  
activerecord (3.2.8, 3.0.0)                 
activeresource (3.2.8, 3.0.0)                   
activesupport (3.2.8, 3.0.0)                    
addressable (2.3.2)                 
akami (1.2.0)                   
arel (3.0.2, 1.0.1)                 
Ascii85 (1.0.1)                 
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)                  
bundler (1.0.22)                    
childprocess (0.3.6)                    
commandline (0.7.10)                    
commonwatir (4.0.0, 2.0.4)                  
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)                   
ffi (1.1.5)                 
gyoku (0.4.6)                   
hike (1.2.1)                    
hoe (3.0.8)                 
httpi (0.9.7)                   
i18n (0.6.1, 0.4.2)                 
journey (1.0.4)                 
libwebsocket (0.1.5)                    
mail (2.4.4, 2.2.19)                    
mime-types (1.19, 1.18)                 
mini_magick (3.2.1)                 
multi_json (1.3.6)                  
mysql2 (0.3.11 x86-mingw32, 0.2.18 x86-mingw32, 0.2.6 x86-mingw32)                  
nokogiri (1.5.5 x86-mingw32)                    
nori (1.1.3)                    
pdf-reader (1.1.1)                  
polyglot (0.3.3)                    
rack (1.4.1, 1.2.5)                 
rack-cache (1.2)                    
rack-mount (0.6.14)                 
rack-ssl (1.3.2)                    
rack-test (0.6.2, 0.5.7)                    
rails (3.0.0)                   
railties (3.0.0)                    
rake (0.8.7)                    
rautomation (0.7.3, 0.6.3)                  
ruby-rc4 (0.1.5)                    
rubygems-update (1.8.24)                    
rubyzip (0.9.9)                 
s4t-utils (1.0.4)                   
savon (0.9.9)                   
selenium-webdriver (2.26.0)                 
sprockets (2.1.3)                   
sqlite3 (1.3.6 x86-mingw32)                 
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)                    
subexec (0.0.4)                 
text-format (1.0.0)                 
text-hyphen (1.0.2)                 
thor (0.14.6)                   
tilt (1.3.3)                    
treetop (1.4.10)                    
tzinfo (0.3.33)                 
user-choices (1.1.6.1)                  
wasabi (2.1.0)                  
watir (4.0.2 x86-mingw32, 2.0.4)                    
watir-classic (3.3.0)                   
watir-webdriver (0.6.2)                 
websocket (1.0.6)                   
win32-api (1.4.8 x86-mingw32)                   
win32-process (0.6.6)                   
win32screenshot (1.0.7)                 
windows-api (0.4.2)                 
windows-pr (1.2.2)                  
xml-simple (1.1.1)                  


Ruby Version:ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]
```

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

`watir/testcase` was removed from Watir recently. I can not find when it was removed, but the information is in [CHANGES](https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/blob/master/CHANGES) file or in [Git history](https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/commits/master).

Comment: Željko Filipin i was not able to find any changes regarding watir/testcase in Git History.

Comment: Based on the rdocs, it was removed in watir-classic 3.1.0 (ie it was last available in watir-classic 3.0.0).

Answer (score 1):

While it would probably be better to move away from Watir::TestCase, if you really need or want to use it, you can re-create it by copying the files from 3.0.

Assume you are using Ruby 1.8, which still has the test-unit gem installed by default, you can do the following:

1) Create a file named 'watir_testcase.rb' with the following code, which is basically a copy of the testcase.rb and assertions.rb file from 3.0:

```
require 'watir-classic'
require 'test/unit'
require 'test/unit/assertions'

module Watir
  # Verification methods used by Watir::TestCase
  module Assertions
  include Test::Unit::Assertions

    # Log a failure if the boolean is true. The message is the failure message logged.
    # Whether true or false, the assertion count is incremented.
    def verify boolean, message = 'verify failed.'
      add_assertion
      add_failure message.to_s, caller unless boolean
    end

    def verify_equal expected, actual, message=nil
      full_message = build_message(message, <<EOT, expected, actual)
<?> expected but was
<?>.
EOT
      verify(expected == actual, full_message)
    end
    def verify_match pattern, string, message=nil
      pattern = case(pattern)
      when String
        Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(pattern))
      else
        pattern
      end
      full_message = build_message(message, "<?> expected to be =~\n<?>.", string, pattern)
      verify(string =~ pattern, full_message)
    end

  end

end

module Test::Unit::Assertions
    def assert_false(boolean, message=nil)
        _wrap_assertion do
            assert_block("assert should not be called with a block.") { !block_given? }
            assert_block(build_message(message, "<?> is not false.", boolean)) { !boolean }
        end
    end
end 

module Watir

  # This is a 'test/unit' testcase customized to exeucte test methods sequentially by default
  # and extra assertions
  #
  class TestCase < Test::Unit::TestCase
    include Watir::Assertions
    @@order = :sequentially
    def initialize name
      throw :invalid_test if name == :default_test && self.class == Watir::TestCase
      super
    end        
    class << self
      attr_accessor :test_methods, :order
      def test_methods
        @test_methods ||= []
      end
      def order
        @order || @@order
      end
      def default_order= order
        @@order = order
      end
      def sorted_test_methods
        case order
        when :alphabetically then          test_methods.sort
        when :sequentially then            test_methods
        when :reversed_sequentially then   test_methods.reverse
        when :reversed_alphabetically then test_methods.sort.reverse
        else raise ArgumentError, "Execute option not supported: #{@order}"
        end
      end
      def suite
        suite = Test::Unit::TestSuite.new(name)
        sorted_test_methods.each do |test|
          catch :invalid_test do
            suite << new(test)
          end
        end
        if (suite.empty?)
          catch :invalid_test do
            suite << new(:default_test)
          end
        end
        return suite
      end
      def method_added id
        name = id.id2name
        test_methods << name if name =~ /^test./
      end
      def execute order
        @order = order
      end
    end
    public :add_assertion
  end    

end
```

2) In your test case files, change the:

```
require 'watir/testcase'
```

to require the newly created file:

```
require './watir_testcase'
```

(ensuring that the path is correct for wherever you saved the file)

Comment: Thanks Justin. I made the changes as you said. But after that i am getting the same load error message. But this time its for the file watir/ie.

Comment: Which part is causing the exception? You need to provide details of the exception (ie the full stacktrace) and the code that it is failing on.